# Linux gcc linking issues

Tags: c++, c

I have two libraries , named ( lib1 and lib2) , both are not dependent on each other. I do not have control over how these libraries are built. When I try to link them the order of linking dictates on different behaviors within the final executable,

For example:

If I link them as [1]

```
gcc $(CC_FLAGS) -o app.out -llib1 -llib2
```

everything works fine

But, if I link them as following [2]

```
gcc $(CC_FLAGS) -o app.out -llib2 -llib1
```

A segmentation fault occurs during executable run.

Any advice or pointer on the cause of this problem would be helpful.

**Update:**

Both of these libraries are dependent on another dynamic library, which is Apache Thrift ( Version 0.11.0) the segfault occurs on lib1 if it is compiled [1] option above, and exception occurs on lib2 if it compiled with option [2] above.

**Update 2**

The issue is due to global namespace violations between the libraries. Since thrift uses IDL mechanism to generate source files, Both libraries ( somehow ) defined the same namespace for their IDL definitions, hence such behavior was observed. Accepting the answer below as correct one since it addresses the question indirectly.

Thank you.

Comment: The order of the libraries is important. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Comment: @zgyarmati: Those answers explain why you might get a linker error, but I don't immediately see why you would get a crash at runtime.

Comment: My bad, thx for clarifying.

Comment: Have you tried investigating the segfault as you would any other?  It could be a boring old memory error (buffer overrun etc) that just happens to be dependent on the precise layout of memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it possible that there resides a symbol (same name) in both of those libs?

Which one the linker will use to resolve an usage of such a symbol depends on the order (not sure where I've read this).

(HINT: This is just a guess)

So lets assume lib1 defines this function:

```c
void foo( int, char* );
```

And lib2 defines:

```c
void foo( int );
```

And somewhere we have a call like:

```
foo( 42 );
```

Now if the linker finds the definition of lib1, this foo most probably will get funny garbage as its 2nd argument.

### Update (reaction to uptdate of question)

It is hard to make precise statements with the insight we have. So I can only point out some guesses and hope they'll help you. So sorry for my inaccuracy here. But I've no idea how else I could continue:

**Guess 1**:

Update says: "*segfault occurs on lib1 if it is compiled [1] option above, and exception occurs on lib2 if it compiled with option [2]*"

ABI incompatible exception handling in lib1? Something like [this](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/ERR59-CPP.+Do+not+throw+an+exception+across+execution+boundaries)?

**Guess 2** (Or should I name it "story"):

Our code inherits (and implements) an abstract class declared in thrift header. This impl then gets passed to lib1/lib2 (through our conflicting symbol) which perform calls to this impl. But lib1 used a different thrift header during compilation (or used conditional compiling, or used another version of thrift).

Comment: Verified that this could happen with dynamic libraries.

Comment: Good catch, in such case it is similar to `#define TRUE FALSE // Happy debugging bastards` :)

Comment: @NateEldredge *both libraries are pulled in, and linking should fail with an error about the multiple definition.*  Not with shared libraries, the linker will just note that the symbol exists as it checks the libraries in order.  If you do an `ldd ...` on the resulting executable you'll see the order the shared objects are loaded in.  In general, the first library loaded with a symbol that matches "wins".  And the match is by symbol name **only** so `foo( int )` will match `foo( char * )` and even `foo( uint64_t *array )`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, apparently both of these libraries are dependent on another dynamic library ( Apache thrift ) , The issue seems to be associated to thrift library loading. Have anyone else experienced this with apache thrift ?